# jQuery height on style element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've a style element inside my body. As I'm doing some complex calculations based on heights of previous elements I ran into that problem. Here is some example code:

HTML

```
<style type="text/css" scoped>
  body {
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
  }
  .log {
    color: white;
  }
</style>

<div class="log"></div>
```

Javascript

```
var $log = $(".log"),
    $style = $("body > style");

$log.append("$.height: " + $style.height() + "<br/>");
$log.append("clientHeight: " + $style[0].clientHeight + "<br/>");
$log.append("offsetHeight: " + $style[0].offsetHeight + "<br/>");
$log.append("scrollHeight: " + $style[0].scrollHeight + "<br/>");
```

Output

```
$.height: 18
clientHeight: 0
offsetHeight: 0
scrollHeight: 0
```

As you can see, jQuery is returning a height for the style element. Is this just a jQuery bug or is it somehow on purpose and I just missed something? I debugged into the jQuery height function and saw they apply `display: block` to the style element, which makes the div having a height.

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/j3dxy4qu/

It just doesn't make any sense to me and destroys my code without a little workaround.

Comment: There is a note about it in official `$.fn.height()` [DOC](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

Comment: @A.Wolff I guess that warning wasn't yellow enough for me, Thanks

Comment: If really this is an issue (not sure how it could be), wrap your style tags inside any element and set on this parent element `display: none`

Comment: Sounds like a pretty nice solution (as long as I remove the scoped attribute of course). Thanks for your help